# Adding a font in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, peoplesoft, ckeditor4.x

I am a Peoplesoft developer. We CKEditor as Rich Text Editor in our Product and this is a delivered feature of the product. Now i have to make some modification to the delivered feature of CKEditor. I need to add an additional font to the delivered fonts of the tool. I have made the changes as mentioned in the blogs-
File name : \ckeditor_source\plugins\font\plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_names =
    'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
    'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
    'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
    'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
    'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
    'Futura LtCn BT/Futura LtCn BT';
```

Even after making the above change i am not able to view the new font in the RTE. Am completely new to javasript. Kindly assis me in which files to be modified. This change is very critical to my next requirement.

Thanks in advance

Vinoth Kanna M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify source files to change editor configuration. Please refer to the [Setting Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) article to choose the configuration method that is best suited to your needs.

Remember to clear your browser cache after introducing any JavaScript/CSS changes!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Anna's answer, you'll need to make sure you're somehow providing a way for the user to get the font. I'm assuming the new font you're wanting to implement is 'Futura LtCn BT/Futura LtCn BT' which is not a standard font. You'll need to specify the location of this font (whether it's on your PS server or elsewhere on the internet) so the user's browser is able to display it.

Here's a good article you might want to read up on:
[How we use web fonts responsibly...](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html) (read the update as well)